# #HgTortoise can i hook command with commit to a concrete branch name?

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, tortoisehg

I need to start Jenkins building specified task, when I commit to a specified branch in repo. Has anyone manage to do something like this?

Comment: Short answer: yes! What versions (hg and Jenkins) are you using? Have you setup the [hg plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mercurial+Plugin)? You set the branch name on the job's config page.

Comment: Hg version 2.8, Jenkins task is set and the branch is set in that task too. I have the hook in hg that starts specified task on jenkins. Now i want to start for example task "A" on Jenkins if I commit changes to branch "BRANCH". I couldn't find any solution how to do it.

Comment: Can you [edit] in your hook? I think you'll need a [custom changeset hook](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) that checks the branch of the commit and triggers Jenkins if appropriate.